# Visual Studio Emulator for Android option is not exists

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, simulator

I'm trying to use this VS 2015 emulator for android
[image]

To be able to use this, I have to use this option
but its not exists on my Visual Studio (its Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2).
[image]

How can I use this Visual Studio emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found the emulator here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)

 Thanks to Yiğit Özaksüt

[and here is the info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/)

Thanks to LukasNimmo